# Returning data from .pop() to use it anywhere

Tags: flutter

I have written a code that return bool type variables. Whether you like the movie. If you like the movie then it returns true, if you don't like the movie then it returns false. But since the .pop() method works in ElevatedButton, I cannot reach it from another class. How can I reach the value?

```
ElevatedButton(
          child: Text(
              "Go to new page"
          ),
          onPressed: () async {
            final answer = await Navigator.of(context).push<bool>(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) {
                    return VideoScreen("Did you like the video?");
                },
              )
            );
          },
        ),
```

However, I cannot say like:

```
    ElevatedButton(
      child: Text(
          "Go to new page"
      ),
      onPressed: () async {
        final answer = await Navigator.of(context).push<bool>(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) {
                return VideoScreen("Did you like the video?");
            },
          )
        );
      },
    ),
    Text(answer)
  ],
);
```

So how can I reach that value? Callback or something? Thanks in advance

Comment: do you mean receive data using `.pop` from the parent route

Comment: Yes that's what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can pass value to parent route while pop like

```dart
Navigator.of(context).pop(YourValue);
```

While you push make sure to await.

```dart
final result =  await Navigator.of(context)....;
print(result);
```

Comment: Printing is okay. But I want to add a text out of button

Comment: Create a state variable and change the value using setStae If i get you correctly

Comment: Where I should create it?

Comment: on parent widget state class, then assign `result` on that variable